# Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ")") read(#<buffer *load*>)

Tags: init-file, debugging, syntax

Launch Emacs using `runemacs --debug-init` and the following error occurred. any idea on how to locate the file/script of the error or how to fix it?  Thanks in advance.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ")")
  read(#<buffer  *load*>)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/user/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1709
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/user/.emacs" "c:/Users/user/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1000be22d>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra right paren, `)`, somewhere in your init file. Here's one way to find it:

1. Start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file).
2. Visit this file - the one that Emacs was trying to load when it barfed:

   ```
    C-x C-f /Users/user/.emacs
   ```
3. Comment out 1/2 of that file (roughly), using `M-x comment-region`.
4. Do `M-x eval-buffer`.

   If you get an error, then comment out half of uncommented part.  If you didn't get an error, uncomment half of the commented part.

Repeat step 4 till you find the problem in your init file. This is a binary search: 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32,...

---

If your init file is small, you might want to instead just look for the extra right paren directly.  You might start at the file beginning and use `C-M-f` to move past each sexp. Sooner or later you'll get to the one with an extra `)`.

---

As @NickD mentioned in a comment, here's another thing to try, and it's quick:

> If you just byte-compile the file, the compiler should tell you where it sees the error (no guarantees that it will actually be there, but it doesn't hurt to check it first, before starting a binary search):
>
> ```
> Compiling file /tmp/foo.el at Mon Nov 25 17:15:31 2019
> foo.el:6:3:Error: Invalid read syntax: ")"
> ```

---

And as @phils mentions in another comment, unmatched parens can be found by using

```
 M-x check-parens
```

which takes you directly to the culprit, so it is quicker.

Comment: If you just byte-compile the file, the compiler should tell you where it sees the error (no guarantees that it will *actually* be there, but it doesn't hurt to check it first, before starting a binary search): `Compiling file /tmp/foo.el at Mon Nov 25 17:15:31 2019
foo.el:6:3:Error: Invalid read syntax: ")"`

Comment: @NickD: Good suggestion. I've added it here, but if you post it as an answer I'll remove it from this answer. Thx.

Comment: `M-x check-parens` will frequently take you there directly.

Comment: Thanks @Drew - I located the extra right paren ) at the very end of .emacs file by going through the whole file which is small. Also it's very good to know the binary search.

Comment: Thanks @NickD too for the compiling file approach. I get a .emacs.elc file ater M-x byte-compile-file and don't know how to check further. can you maybe add details to your foo.el example? Appreciated.

Comment: If there is an extra paren at the end, you *should* get an error from the compiler when you byte-compile it. It appears in the `*Compile-Log*` buffer. Does this not happen? Also, there is no .elc file produced in my case when that error pops up, so I'm not sure what is happening with your .emacs file.